# How to trigger the class and append the content in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to trigger the class "alert success" when the button is clicked in HTML,

The code is:

```js
function appendText() {
  var title = $("#title").val();
  var content = $("#content").val();
  var type = $("#type").val();
  var markup = "<div>" + title + content + "</div>";
  $(".alert success").append(markup);
  $(".closebtn").append()
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p style="margin-top: 2%">
  <select id="type">
    <option value="success">success</option>
    <option value="info">info</option>
    <option value="warning">warning</option>
    <option value="error">error</option>
  </select>
  <label for="title">title:</label>
  <input type="text" value="title" id="title">
  <label for="content">content:</label>
  <input type="text" id="content" value="content" style="width: 50%">
  <button onclick="appendText()">Add Notification</button>
</p>
```

I need to create dynamically the following HTML code when the button is clicked.

```
<div class="alert success">
  <span class="closebtn">&times;</span>  
  <strong>Success!</strong> Indicates a successful or positive action.
</div>
```

Can you suggest the correct Jquery code for my need?

Comment: `$(".alert success")` should be `$(".alert.success")` else the jquery code would believe that it should look for a `success` element within the `alert` element

Comment: What's `$(".closebtn").append()` for?

Comment: it will create delete button in a row element

Comment: Yes. It works as $(".alert.success")

Comment: See the working solution below and also the close button you are appending is working as well in my answer below. Hope it helps. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is working and simplified snippet.

Its appending the notification data and also the `closebtn` **close button** is working as well and deleting the clicked notification.

Just run snippet to see in action.

```js
function appendText() {
  var title = $("#title").val();
  var content = $("#content").val();
  var type = $("#type").val();
  var markup = "<div class='results'><button class='closebtn' onclick='closeAlert(this)'>X</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;" + type + ' ' + title + ' ' + content + "</div>";

  if (type === 'success') {
    $('.messages').css({
      "background-color": "green"
    });
  } else if (type === 'warning') {
    $('.messages').css({
      "background-color": "yellow"
    });
  } else if (type === 'error') {
    $('.messages').css({
      "background-color": "red"
    });
  } else if (type === 'info') {
    $('.messages').css({
      "background-color": "blue"
    });
  }
  $(".messages").html(markup);
}

function closeAlert(_this) {
  $(_this).parent().remove()
}
```

```css
label,
button {
  display: block;
}

.results {
  display: flex;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p style="margin-top: 2%">
  <select id="type">
    <option value="success">success</option>
    <option value="info">info</option>
    <option value="warning">warning</option>
    <option value="error">error</option>
  </select>
  <label for="title">title:</label>
  <input type="text" value="title" id="title">
  <label for="content">content:</label>
  <input type="text" id="content" value="content" style="width: 50%">
  <button onclick="appendText()">Add Notification</button>
</p>

<div class="messages"></div>
```

Comment: Based on the condition of success, info, warning, error, I need to change the background color as well. Can I put the if statement in Jquery?

Comment: @Balamurugan I have updated my answer please check. Its loading the color dynamically to the notification selected. Do not forget to upvote and accept as "the" answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function appendText() {
  var title = $("#title").val();
  var content = $("#content").val();
  var type = $("#type").val();
  var result = '<div>'
  + title + ' ' + content
  + '<div class="alert success">'
  + '<span class="closebtn">&times;</span>'
  + '<strong>Success!</strong> Indicates a successful or positive action.'
  + '</div>'
  + '</div>';
  $('#result').append(result);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p style="margin-top: 2%">
  <select id="type">
    <option value="success">success</option>
    <option value="info">info</option>
    <option value="warning">warning</option>
    <option value="error">error</option>
  </select>
  <label for="title">title:</label>
  <input type="text" value="title" id="title">
  <label for="content">content:</label>
  <input type="text" id="content" value="content" style="width: 50%">
  <button onclick="appendText()">Add Notification</button>
</p>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

*For HTML Tags or Content*

```
var content = "Hello World";
$(".className").html(content);
```

Or

```
var content = "<b>Hello World</b>";
$(".className").html(content);
```